# Reading eID data in java android

Tags: java, android, usb, smartcard, apdu

Setting: I need to read data form an eID smartcard using a built in reader from the android device in java.

I first try to power on the device. This returns me a lot of 0 bytes. This makes me think it already fails here? When I try to perform a read command I again get 0 bytes for the data part.
Am I misunderstanding how to perform these instructions or is there a key part that I am missing?

This is all new to me and not my usual cup of tea.

```java
public void readCard() {
        powerOnReader();
        getPermission();
        setDevice();
        setEndpoints();
        sendPowerOnCCIDCommand();
        sendReadCCIDCommand();
    }
```

##### First I send the poweron command to the endpoint:

```java
public void sendPowerOnCCIDCommand() {
        int dataTransferred = 0;
        byte[] PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn = hexStringToByteArray("62" + "00000000" + "00" + "00" + "00" + "0000");
        if (epOut != null) {
            dataTransferred = smartCardConnection.bulkTransfer(epOut, PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn, PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn.length, 2000);
        }

        write(smartCardConnection, epOut, PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn);
        read(smartCardConnection, epIn);
    }
```

This returns the following:

`80  00  00  00  00  00  00  41  FE  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00`

##### Next I try to perform a read operation:

the APDU instruction for this read operation should be the following:
`00 A4 08 0C 06 3F00 DF01 4031`

```java
public void sendReadCCIDCommand() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SENDREAD");
        byte[] command = hexStringToByteArray("6F" + "0C000000" + "00" + "01" + "00" + "0000" + "00" + "A4" + "08" + "0C" + "06" +"3F00" +"DF01" + "4031");

        write(smartCardConnection, epOut, command);
        read(smartCardConnection, epIn);
    }
```

This returns the following:

`80  00  00  00  00  00  01  41  FE  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00`

##### The read and write functions:

```java
public int read(UsbDeviceConnection connection, UsbEndpoint epIn) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[epIn.getMaxPacketSize()];
        int byteCount = 0;
        byteCount = connection.bulkTransfer(epIn, buffer, buffer.length, 500);
        
        if (byteCount >= 0) {
            for (byte bb : buffer) {
                result.append(String.format(" %02X ", bb));
            }
        } 

        return byteCount;
    }

    public void write(UsbDeviceConnection connection, UsbEndpoint epOut, byte[] command) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        connection.bulkTransfer(epOut, command, command.length, 1000);
        for (byte bb : command) {
            result.append(String.format(" %02X ", bb));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you describe as "read command" is actually a SELECT according to ISO 7816-4.  Since you provide no LE and P2 indicates no response data wanted I would only expect SW1/SW2, i. e. 90 00 in case of success.